# Standard Interpolation between Bochner spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, interpolation, weak-convergence

I've read the following in a few papers:

Given: Let $\Omega \subset R^d$ be a Lipschitz domain. A sequence $f_n$ converges strongly to $f$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and
weakly in $L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$.

Then by a standard interpolation argument it follows that 
$f_n$ converges strongly to $f$ in $L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$.

Now my question is what is meant by standard interpolation argument?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: A comment about the title "Standard interpolation between..." -- the word "standard" in your papers refers to "argument", not to "interpolation". They are not talking about some "standard interpolation".

Comment: You are right, I was to quick writing the title. Any ideas what is mathematically meant by this standard argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look for a book on interpolation theory, there is, e.g., a great introduction by Tartar.

There are, typically, two interpolation results:
$$\|u\|_{L^p} \le \|u\|_{L^r}^\mu \, \|u\|_{L^s}^{1-\mu},$$
(Lebesgue scale), if $1/p = \mu/r + (1-\mu)/s$ and
$$\|u\|_{H^1} \le C \, \|u\|_{L^2}^{1/2} \, \|u\|_{H^2}^{1/2}$$ (Sobolev scale).

Your proof requires the second one (use boundedness in $H^2$).

Comment: Ok thanks. So taking the square in the second interpolation inequality, integration over (0,T) and applying Hölder's inequality does the job...